# C# - In my datagrid when I used a stored procedure with order by 'Id' Desc my form does not show with Desc

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datagridview

This is the problem.

My stored procedure:

[image]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FASV1_GetChangesOnProduct_Desc]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM ChangesOnProduct 
    ORDER BY IdLog DESC
END
GO


EXEC [FASV1_GetChangesOnProduct_Desc]
```

My code in C#:

[image]

And the big problem in my datagridview:

[image]

Comment: Add code to your question as formatted code rather than as an image.

Comment: An update to DGV doesn't automatically get repainted.  So the trick is to set the DataSource to null : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: @Math; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an item from a list to another list in a `foreach` block will preserve order from the source (first list).

Also, `WinForm DataGridView` does not support ordering for List `DataSource`, So it couldn't happen in control.

Trace your code carefully. If you could not find any clue, use this :

```
LChangeDataGridView.DataSource = LChange.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();
```